# How to creat "grayscale" image from float or int values in ITK?

Tags: itk

If I have some:

```
-------------
float values
-----------------------
0.9   0.6   0.3   0.1   0.0                          
0.7   0.5   0.1   0.0   0.0               
0.3   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.0  

or int values
-----------------------
22 15 10  7  0        
44 35 20 10  0          
12 8  6  4   1
```

How Can I create a grayscale image from these values in ITK, in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

You might find what you are looking for in this example: http://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageIntensity/ConvertRGBImageToGrayscaleImage/Documentation.html

Anyway, you need to convert your data matrix to an itk::Image before you can do that. For that goal take a look at the official guide: http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf section 'Importing Image Data from a Buffer'. Once you are done with this just take a look at the output image, that might be exactly what you are looking for (there might be no need to apply the luminance filter in the first example)